# How to write bash output to arbitrary program stdin

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io

I want to (hopefully easily) write from a bash script to any arbitrary program that is already running via that program's stdin.

Say I have some arbitrary program "Sum", that constantly takes user input from the terminal. Every integer it receives from stdin it adds to the current sum and outputs the new sum. Here's example terminal text of what I mean:

```
$: ./Sum
Sum: 0
Give me an integer: 2
Sum: 2
Give me an integer: 5
Sum: 7
```

How would automate this process in a bash script? If I had control of Sum's source code I could let it accept integer arguments. But if I *don't* have said control of the program, how can I automate the interaction with Sum? Here's a psuedo code of a bash snippet of what I *want* to do:

In example.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
my_program_input_point=./Sum &
echo 2 > my_program_input_point
echo 5 > my_program_input_point
```

Thus on my terminal screen it would still look like this:

```
$: ./example.sh
Sum: 0
Give me an integer: 2
Sum: 2
Give me an integer: 5
Sum: 7
```

The difference is I wouldn't have typed any of it.

It feels like this task should be really easy, because basically anything you can do in a terminal, you can also easily do in a script. Except, apparently, directly interact with an arbitrary process once its started.

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376944/bash-script-redirecting-stdin-to-program-and-its-output-to-another-program) answers some aspects of my question by using pipes. However the accepted answer only works if I have control of both programs on each side of the pipe, the "recipient" program is under no obligation to read from the pipe automatically.

This is assuming I can't modify the program/script in question. I also can't write a "pipe reader" script to wrap around the program (Sum), because that wrapper script would still be required to interact with the running process Sum.

The second answer to [this question on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process) (written by jfgagne)  seems much closer, but I can't seem to get it working. Is there any *easier* way to do this that I just don't know about?

---

For information on how to capture and read an arbitrary program's output, see my next [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757914/in-bash-how-to-parse-and-or-redirect-stdout-for-an-arbitrary-program-i-am-backgr/39760939#39760939) for more information

Comment: Your example could be written as `printf '%s\n' 2 5 | ./Sum`. Are you really looking for something else?

Comment: Yeah, the issue there is if don't have all the input I want to send to Sum available at the same time. Sum is a trivial example, so that happening would be unlikely. However, what if I want to do this:
`printf '%s\n' 2 5 | [a running instance of sum]; some other logic;
printf '%s\n' 2 5 | [the same running instance of sum as before]`

Comment: Then use grouping: `{ printf '%s\n' 2 5; some other stuff; printf '%s\n' 2 5; } | ./Sum`. For a more comfortable writing, you can put your stuff in a function: `mystuff() { printf '%s\n' 2 5; some other stuff; printf '%s\n' 2 5; }` and run as `mystuff | ./Sum` (or in a script).

Comment: not being able to start `sum` is a hard requirement or is this an XY question?

Comment: Just realized my comment above is exactly what John Kugelman suggests in his answer below `:)`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. My bash script can start `Sum` in the background for me, but I want to be able to write to `Sum` at any point in my script.

Comment: For that, you already have a solution. What's the question then?

Comment: I want to `./Sum &; do some other logic; echo 3 > Sum; do some other logic (maybe check output from Sum!); echo 8 > Sum;`

Comment: Your solution already does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a named pipe. Whatever starts `Sum` is responsible for creating the named pipe some place convenient, then starting `Sum` with the named pipe as its standard input.

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
Sum < /tmp/pipe
```

Then your script could take the name of the pipe as an argument, then treat it as a file it can write to.

```
#!/bin/bash
p=$1

echo 2 > "$p"
echo 5 > "$p"
```

Then you could call your script with `client /tmp/pipe`.

Comment: I have yet to figure out how to properly capture stdout from `./Sum < /tmp/pipe`, but this answer does in fact work. I want to point out two things. 1) This answers the question in a way that John Kugelman's does not, it allows for piping input into the process AFTER the process has been started, potentially allowing a script to parse the process's output before piping information into it. 2) A process can be launched in the same script that pipes data to it by backgrounding the process `./Sum.sh < /tmp/sumpipe &`

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way is to use a pipeline. The trick is that you can make the lefthand side of the pipeline a compound statement, or a function call. It doesn't have to be just a single command.

```
{
    echo 2
    echo 5
} | ./Sum
```

or

```
numbers() {
    echo 2
    echo 5
}

numbers | ./Sum
```

This lets you do whatever you want to generate the input. You don't have to have it all ahead of time. If you generate the input bit by bit, it'll be fed to `./Sum` bit by bit.

Comment: I like this, and it's definitely better, and would solve a bunch of use cases I see in my head. A problem with this though, is that all of the output I generate in numbers() would be fed to `Sum` all at the same time. If `numbers()` needed to make some decisions based on `Sum`'s output, I wouldn't be able to. Something like `echo 2; if [ "$sum_output" == 2 ]; then echo 5 fi`

Comment: @durandaltheta: you can use coprocesses: `coproc ./Sum; { printf '%s' 2 5; stuff; printf '%s\n' 2 5; } <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}; kill $COPROC_PID`. But I guess it's going to be messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the standard input file descriptor of the running process. Here is the same question: https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi

You need to write to `/proc/*pid of the program*/fd/0` which is the file descriptor for the standard input of the process with that `pid`. Make sure you have access to do this.

Comment: I actually don't *know* the answer to this, but there is a comment [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process) for the first answer (the accepted answer, and it's very similar to your answer) written by Feuermurmel that says this doesn't work and simply writes to the terminal. Can you provide some clarification on this?